# Joomla 3 RSS url syntax

Tags: joomla, rss, syndication

I am building a network of Joomla 3.x websites for a company. There will be one over-arching "master site" and then a series of "mini-sites" for each company division. Each mini-site will have its own news blog layout page.

I need to aggregate all the news from the mini-sites to the master site. My plan thus far has been to set up RSS feeds from each of the mini-site news pages and pull those feeds into the master site using menu item "news feed > single news feed".

The problem is that Joomla 3 does not seem to recognise its own RSS feeds. I think it comes down to the syntax of the URL which is...

```
http://minisite1.mydomain.com/news?format=feed&type=rss
```

When I put this URL into any other RSS reader they too throw errors so this must be where the error lies.

I must be doing something fairly fundamentally wrong here but I can't figure what it must be. Can anyone suggest a solution? Or perhaps an alternative way of aggregating content from different Joomla websites?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues finding the RSS url on a page you can always add the `Syndication Feeds` module (default in Joomla) to the page. The page has to be a blog layout for the module to show/work. When the module is displayed, click on the RSS icon for a new page to display the feed URL.

Well once you gather each of your feeds URI's, most commonly,   `minisite1.mydomain.com/news/index.php?format=feed&type=rss`, you can insert them into this **FREE** module available from Joomla Works at: http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free/simple-rss-feed-reader

After downloading, their module allows you to display each feed merged as if it were one feed (of course the order of each displayed depends on timestamp of each post).

Comment: Obviously that's how I got the RSS feed from the mini sites - using Joomla's onboard Syndication component. I have also already tried and dismissed this module - I can't tell if it works or not because the admin section seems to be incomplete or erroneous - there is no "menu assignment" tab so I cannot activate the module.

Comment: Hmm... I think you might have to ignore my last comment - I think I may have just stumbled on a bug in my Joomla installation - it appears that none of the modules are showing the menu assignment tab... furrther investigation is required!

Comment: Yep - fixed that issue (totally local to my system) however that module really seems to be flawed - it threw a bunch of errors associated with the helper.php file. Now uninstalled. Currently writing my own solution :)